# Kinesis: Is it possible to connect Firehose and another consumer as if there were two independent consumers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a kinesis stream with a custom kafka consumer reading data, processing it, and managing its offsets. What I'd like to do is also dump the raw data feed into S3 using Kinesis Firehose.

Does Kinesis Firehose consume Kinesis Streams in the same way as any other consumer, i.e. does it maintain its own index so that all consumers will get the entire set of records?

Comment: have you got an answer for your question?